# Python and openCV to android APK

Tags: android, python, opencv, apk

I want to transform my python code into an Android app. The problem I saw is I'm using openCV in the code, and I didn't found anything related to generate an APK while using openCV.
There is a way to generate an APK from python and openCV?

Answer (score 1):

There is SL4A / PythonForAndroid but unfortunately it uses hardcoded Java RMI invocations for anything os related. That means that there are no OpenCV bindings.

I guess you'll have to learn Java