# Python - How to convert an opencv .py script to .apk?

Tags: python, android, opencv

I vould like to convert my python script which uses opencv and camera to an .apk file so that it can be used on android. My script finds edges and uses live camera. And when converting it I helped with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-6rwrstImI. First I tryed using his code and following his steps. In the result the program worked and it displayed the image as used in the tuturial. But when I tryed making it work for my own camera based program it crashed. Any ideas?

I belive that I made an error when making the window dimensions, vould it be better if the window was displayed in pygame instead of opencv?

**Here is my script (main.py):**

```
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,120) 
cap.set(4,160)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 100)
    cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
    

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To convert it to a .apk file I firstly uploaded my script to google colab and than I used these commands (they are shown under the tutorial video):

- !pip install opencv-python
- !pip install buildozer
- !pip install cython==0.29.19
- !sudo apt-get install -y 
  python3-pip 
  build-essential 
  git 
  python3 
  python3-dev 
  ffmpeg 
  libsdl2-dev 
  libsdl2-image-dev 
  libsdl2-mixer-dev 
  libsdl2-ttf-dev 
  libportmidi-dev 
  libswscale-dev 
  libavformat-dev 
  libavcodec-dev 
  zlib1g-dev
- !sudo apt-get install -y 
  libgstreamer1.0 
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base 
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
- !sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6
- !sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
- !buildozer init
- !buildozer -v android debug

Than I just changed app name in the buildozer.spec file (title = Camera app), and after it finished, I installed the app on my phone via USB cable, like I did after following the tutorial.

But, whan I ran it it just crashed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sadly, there are no OpenCV to apk converters. Here is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664845/python-and-opencv-to-android-apk